# How do I obtain the DateTime from a GridView and add it into a TextBox when I click a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to get the values from both the date fields shown in my GridView and input them in the TextBox shown below in the Panel by clicking a button. I can't seem to get the date values by using the rowindex and the corresponding cell.

This is my GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="ClientContracts" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-sm" ItemType="ScheduleStarterKit.ViewModels.ContractInfo" 
            DataKeyNames="ContractId"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnRowCommand="ClientContracts_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="Edit" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From">
                    <ItemTemplate><%# Item.Duration.From.ToLongDateString() %></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To">
                    <ItemTemplate><%# Item.Duration.To.ToLongDateString() %></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I want the DateTime from Cells 2 and 3 and input it into the corresponding TextBox below

```
<asp:Panel ID="AddEditPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <hr />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ContractTitle">Contract Title</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ContractTitle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Requirements">Requirements</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Requirements" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="FromDate">Duration</asp:Label>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">From</span>
                        </div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="FromDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" />
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">To</span>
                            </div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ToDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="SaveContract" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="SaveContract_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

This is my code behind

```
int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            ContractTitle.Text = ClientContracts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
            FromDate.Text = ClientContracts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
            ToDate.Text = ClientContracts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
```

Comment: It looks like you might be binding something to the ````CommandArgument```` which would be helpful to know what that is.

Comment: It would just be the GridViewCommandEventArgs

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are quite a few ways to do this.

First up:

The event that triggers (due to the CommandName="Select" - VERY important - row index changed will NOT fire if you don't have this).

So, in event GridView SelectedIndexChanged

You can do this IN EVENT Selected index changed:

```
  GridViewRow gV = ClientContracts.SelectedRow;
  FromDate.Text = gV.Cells[2].Text;
  ToDate.Text =   gV.Cells[3].Text;
```

however, your date fields are now text, and you might well want to keep then as date value types.

You can also in place of a buttonField, drop in a actual asp button. Say like this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select"
                            CommandName="Select"
                            MyStartDate = '<%# Items.Duration.From %>'
                            MyEndDate = '<%# Items.Duration.From %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Note how we simple add some custom tags.

now, in row selected index changed?

we go:

```
    Dim gV As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow

    Dim MyButton As Button = gV.FindControl("btnSelect")

    ' startdate = MyButton.Attributes("MyStartDate")
```

Comment: so the first part gives me an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object. So I feel that since im getting the DateTime directly from an SQL database wont I just need to somehow get that information from the GridView and input it in the TextBox? I feel as if the answer is simple but I cant for the life of me figure out how to get a DateTime and not a Text

Comment: Since ` ContractTitle.Text = ClientContracts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text; ` this code prints out the Title on the ContractTitle TextBox, I just need to do the same for date right?

Comment: Ah - I see you followed up. You got this. My spider sense would prefer that the date is always stored as native, but your formatting seems to have fixed this. If serious time, datediff() or other types of calculations have to occur on this? Then I would pull the row based on PK - and operate directly against the actual datetime and NOT as a string. But it looks like you are ok with your follow up. So, in some cases I will based everything on the PK row and pull it into a data table. It not clear if you have a "class" (entity frame work, or the data-set designer between you and the data).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Sorry if how I asked my question was hard to understand.

I simply had to change my FromDate.Text and ToDate.Text code behind to this

`FromDate.Text = DateTime.Parse((ClientContracts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

`ToDate.Text = DateTime.Parse((ClientContracts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`